# Is there an easy way to turn Future<Future<T>> into Future<T>?

Tags: java, concurrency, guava

I've got some code that submits a request to another thread which may or may not submit that request to yet another thread.  That yields a return type of `Future<Future<T>>`.  Is there some non-heinous way to immediately turn this into `Future<T>` that waits on the completion of the entire future chain?

I'm already using the Guava library to handle other fun concurrency stuff and as a replacement for Google Collections and its working well but I can't seem to find something for this case.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a little more context.  The obvious answer is to call get(),but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Done.  Sorry it wasn't clear.

Comment: Sounds like you need Monad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guava 13.0 adds [`Futures.dereference`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#dereference%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture%29) to do this. It requires a `ListenableFuture<ListenableFuture>`, rather than a plain `Future<Future>`. (Operating on a plain `Future` would require a makeListenable call, each of which requires a dedicated thread for the lifetime of the task (as is made clearer by the method's new name, [`JdkFutureAdapters.listenInPoolThread`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/JdkFutureAdapters.html#listenInPoolThread%28java.util.concurrent.Future%29)).)

Answer (score 7):

Another possible implementation that uses the guava libraries and is a lot simpler.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.*;
import com.google.common.base.*;

public class FFutures {
  public <T> Future<T> flatten(Future<Future<T>> future) {
    return Futures.chain(Futures.makeListenable(future), new Function<Future<T>, ListenableFuture<T>>() {
      public ListenableFuture<T> apply(Future<T> f) {
        return Futures.makeListenable(f);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it'd do it and let me delegate all Future handing to guava.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best that can be done to implement the contract of Future. I took the tack of being as unclever as possible so as to be sure that it meets the contract. Not especially the implementation of get with timeout.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Futures {
  public <T> Future<T> flatten(Future<Future<T>> future) {
    return new FlattenedFuture<T>(future);
  }

  private static class FlattenedFuture<T> implements Future<T> {
    private final Future<Future<T>> future;

    public FlattenedFuture(Future<Future<T>> future) {
      this.future = future;
    }

    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
      if (!future.isDone()) {
        return future.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
      } else {
        while (true) {
          try {
            return future.get().cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
          } catch (CancellationException ce) {
            return true;
          } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
            return false;
          } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // pass
          }
        }
      }
    }

    public T get() throws InterruptedException, 
                          CancellationException, 
                          ExecutionException 
    {
      return future.get().get();
    }

    public T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, 
                                                     CancellationException, 
                                                     ExecutionException, 
                                                     TimeoutException 
    {
      if (future.isDone()) {
        return future.get().get(timeout, unit);
      } else {
        return future.get(timeout, unit).get(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }
    }

    public boolean isCancelled() {
      while (true) {
        try {
          return future.isCancelled() || future.get().isCancelled();
        } catch (CancellationException ce) {
          return true;
        } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
          return false;
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
          // pass
        }
      }
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
      return future.isDone() && innerIsDone();
    }

    private boolean innerIsDone() {
      while (true) {
        try {
          return future.get().isDone();
        } catch (CancellationException ce) {
          return true;
        } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
          return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
          // pass
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class like:

```
public class UnwrapFuture<T> implements Future<T> {
    Future<Future<T>> wrappedFuture;

    public UnwrapFuture(Future<Future<T>> wrappedFuture) {
        this.wrappedFuture = wrappedFuture;
    }

    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        try {
            return wrappedFuture.get().cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //todo: do something
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            //todo: do something
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You'll have to deal with exceptions that get() can raise but other methods cannot.

Comment: Thats pretty much what I was trying to avoid.  Also that cancel method you've got there will make cancel wait until the first future in the chain is done.  Thats definitely not what I'm looking for.

Comment: "turn this into Future<T> that waits on the completion of the entire future chain?" ... 

I don't think you can cancel the second future until you get a hold of it.  But you cannot get it until the first future returns it.

Comment: Good catch.  While the second future is a created by the first one I'm sure you could get yourself into a state where you've canceled the first future but it makes the second one anyway and you can't cancel it.

I bet you could fix that by `Futures.makeListenable`-ing the first future and adding a listener that immediately cancels the chained future on return.  The problem then becomes testing for that case.

Answer (score 0):

This was my first stab at it but I'm sure there is plenty wrong with it.  I'd be more than happy to just replace it with something like `Futures.compress(f)`.

```
public class CompressedFuture<T> implements Future<T> {
    private final Future<Future<T>> delegate;

    public CompressedFuture(Future<Future<T>> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        if (delegate.isDone()) {
            return delegate.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        }
        try {
            return delegate.get().cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching a finished future", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching a finished future", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return delegate.get().get();
    }

    @Override
    public T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + unit.toMillis(timeout);
        Future<T> next = delegate.get(timeout, unit);
        return next.get(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        if (!delegate.isDone()) {
            return delegate.isCancelled();
        }
        try {
            return delegate.get().isCancelled();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching a finished future", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching a finished future", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        if (!delegate.isDone()) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            return delegate.get().isDone();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching a finished future", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching a finished future", e);
        }
    }
}
```